# Sticky blocks in 2D elastic collisions with VPython

Tags: python, collision-detection, collision, bounce, vpython

I'm trying to implement the famous elastic collision problem introduced in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HEfHFsfGXjs).

I'm using VPython to simulate the whole thing, however my code isn't running properly for some reason; it seems like when the third collision occurs, the blocks are "colliding" indefinitely (the collision counter keeps increasing), and the blocks are then sticked together. They're even going through the wall instead of bouncing on it and I can't figure out why.

Here is my code:

```py
from vpython import *
import numpy as np
import time


def compute_pi(number_of_digits):
    scene = canvas(width=1280, height=720, range=3.8, center=vec(6, 0, 0))
    scene.title = 'Computing PI with collisions'

    # blocks
    small_block = box(
        pos=vec(2.0, -2.5, 0.0), 
        size=vec(1.0, 1.0, 0.01), 
        color=vec(0.5, 1.0, 0.3)
    )
    large_block = box(
        pos=vec(4.0, -2.0, 0.0), 
        size=vec(2.0, 2.0, 0.01), 
        color=vec(1.0, 0.5, 0.3)
    )

    # wall & ground
    wall = box(
        pos=vec(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), 
        size=vec(0.1, 6, 0.01), 
        color=vec(1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
    )
    ground = box(
        pos=vec(9.95, -3.0, 0.0), 
        size=vec(20, 0.1, 0.01), 
        color=vec(1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
    )

    # initial conditions
    small_block.m = 1.0
    large_block.m = 100 ** (number_of_digits - 1)
    small_block.vel = vec(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
    large_block.vel = vec(-0.01, 0.0, 0.0)

    t = 0
    dt = 0.05
    collisions_counter = 0

    time.sleep(0.5)

    while True:
        rate(1000)
        large_block.pos += large_block.vel * dt
        small_block.pos += small_block.vel * dt

        # wall collision
        if (small_block.pos.x - small_block.size.x / 2 < wall.pos.x + wall.size.x / 2):
            small_block.vel *= -1
            collisions_counter += 1
            print ("Number of collisions: " + str(collisions_counter))

        # blocks collision
        if (small_block.pos.x + small_block.size.x / 2 > large_block.pos.x - large_block.size.x / 2):
            small_block.vel = ((small_block.m - large_block.m) / (small_block.m + large_block.m)) * small_block.vel + ((2 * large_block.m) / (small_block.m + large_block.m)) * large_block.vel
            large_block.vel = ((2 * small_block.m) / (small_block.m + large_block.m)) * small_block.vel + ((large_block.m - small_block.m) / (small_block.m + large_block.m)) * large_block.vel
            collisions_counter += 1
            print ("Number of collisions: " + str(collisions_counter))

        t += dt
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't study all your physics here, but I think you may have fallen victim to the following issue: When there is a collision that reverses the x component of velocity, it seems natural simply to set vx = -vx. Unfortunately, if the most recent move went deeply enough past the boundary, you can get oscillatory fibrilation if in the next time interval you are still enough past the boundary to again flip the sign of the charge. A safer test is to be explicit: If you ever find the position to be the right of the boundary, explicitly set vx = -abs(vx), and if to the left of the boundary, explicitly set vx = abs(vx).

Comment: For VPython questions it's better to post to the VPython forum, where there are many more VPython users who will see your question than if you post to stackoverflow:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups&hl=en#!forum/vpython-users